# tkinter sequential execution ordering

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sequence, execution

I am having trouble with this code that won't execute code at a certain point. I can't really describe the problem in wording, but in the code, the remaining code under `window.mainloop()` will not run as I need it to unless the main window (gui) is closed which is problematic. I want to be able to `print(t.test)` when all the code under def calculate has been completely executed. I technically could do it with removing `window.mainloop()` but this will run the code before I can gather input which is vital. I need to keep the structure of the coding the same as shown below as well.

```
import tkinter

class Test:

  def __init__(self):
    self.test = False

def calculate(window, userinput, t):
  test = userinput.get()
  print(test)
  window.destroy()
  t.test = True

def main():

  t = Test()
  gui = tkinter.Tk()
  gui.title("example window")
  gui.geometry("400x400")

  userinput = tkinter.StringVar()

  window = tkinter.Toplevel()
  window.title("Entry")
  tkinter.Message(window, text="Label", width="200").pack()
  tkinter.Entry(window, width=30, textvariable=userinput).pack()
  tkinter.Button(window, text="ok", command=lambda: calculate(window, userinput, t)).pack()
  window.mainloop()

  print(t.test)

  gui.mainloop()

main()
```

**EDIT:**
It seems I was able to make it behave the same way and keep the same structure by putting `print(t.test)` under its own defined function and then calling it under `def calculate(userinput, window, t)` in the last line. I tested this but it causes the main window to freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way tkinter is designed to work is that you:

1. create your widgets
2. call mainloop (exactly once)
3. the window is destroyed and the program exits

You shouldn't call mainloop more than once, and you shouldn't have more code after the call to mainloop.

If you want something to run after the call to mainloop, schedule it with `after`:

```
...
gui.after(1, do_something)
gui.mainloop()
```

Anything scheduled by `after` will run after the mainloop has started.